# Seaborn jointplot options erased with tight_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem with the use of tight_layout combined with jointplot. I have a dataframe `df` with my datas in two columns.

I create a jointplot with the command:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
sns.jointplot(df["time (ns)"],df["intesity (counts/s)"], kind='kde', shade=True, cmap="RdBu_r", n_levels=1000, space=0)
```

The problem is that the axis labels are partially outside of the figure: I solved using

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Anyway this have the side effect to "erase" the `space=0` option, resulting in a graph different from what I would like to obtain. Does someone knows how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)
```

after `tight_layout()`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.